# Can we use multiple elements with except operator in xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to add multiple matches in except operator.
Example:

```
<root>
  <div>
    <span style="font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;">
    </span>
    <h3>hi</h3>
    <ol><li>hello</li></ol>
    <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
    <p>name</p>
</div>
</root>
```

Expected result: Want to convert div tag to p tag and then move only h3,ol,ul,p tag out of it if present.

```
<root>
  <p>
    <span style="font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;">
    </span>
  </p>
    <h3>hi</h3>
    <ol><li>hello</li></ol>
    <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
    <p>name</p>
</root>
```

I tried this:

```
     <xsl:template match="div">
   <p>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* except h3"/>
   </p>
          <xsl:copy-of select="h3"/>    
  </xsl:template>
```

Above xslt results to :

```
 <root>
      <p>
        <span style="font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;">
        </span>
        <ol><li>hello</li></ol>
        <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
        <p>name</p>
      </p>
        <h3>hi</h3>
    </root>
```

Is there any way to add mutiple element names in except operator like `<xsl:copy-of select="* except h3 and ol"/>`

Another approach i tried:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[p | ol | ul | h3 | h2]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- convert <div> to <p> if it's direct child is not one of p,ol,ul -->
    <xsl:template match="div[not(p | ol | ul | h3 | h2)]">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
```

And this results to which is wrong as i still want span tag to be under p tag:

```
 <root><span style="font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;">
    </span>
    <h3>hi</h3>
    <ol><li>hello</li></ol>
    <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
    <p>name</p></root>
```

Answer (score 2):

In stead of using `xsl:copy` you could just use the `xsl:apply-templates` approach like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div/span">
    <p>
      <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `except` operator was introduced in XPath 2.0 so it doesn't make any sense on how to use it with XSLT 1.0 which uses XPath 1.0.

As for its use where supported, you can of course do e.g. `* except (h3, ol)`.

In XPath 1.0 you can try e.g. `*[not(self::h3|self::ol)]`.

Comment: But when i'm trying this it's working here with version 1 https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVbT

Comment: If you use Saxon 10 as you do there you use an XSLT 3.0 processor supporting XPath 3.1, it doesn't matter what you declare as the XSLT version in your code, other than switching to backwards compatibility for some constructs.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for info and i think except will not work in my case so is there any other way to do that in xslt 1?

Comment: i added one more approach at the end of my question but still an issue.

Comment: You need the identity template and this -   <xsl:template match="div">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::h3|self::ol|self::ul|self::p)]"/>
      </p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[self::h3|self::ol|self::ul|self::p]"/>
    </xsl:template>     according to Martin's suggestion.

Comment: Yeah got it..Thanks @Bluewood66 and Martin

Comment: @rajatsethi, note for the `except` in XSLT/XPath 1 I would use `select="*[not(self::h3|self::ol|self::ul|self::p)]"` as suggested by Bluewood66 but for the normal selection I would just use `select="h3 | ol | ul | p"`.

Comment: @rajatsethi Martin's suggestion is better.  It's the right way to go.  I would recommend using it.